# Stay usb power on after shutdown on windows 10

Tags: usb, windows-10, power-management

I have `MSI-P45 Diamond` motherboard and `Windows 10 64bit`. I'd like to enable usb ports power after shutdown.
If I turn off the PC from `Windows` they won't stay on but if I press power button after `POST` screen they stay on.

I tried with the following settings:

`BIOS` Settings:

```
Power Management Setup:
```

[image: Power Management Setup]

```
Wake Up Event Setup
```

[image: Wake Up Event Setup]

`Windows` Settings:

- `Power Options` > `High performance`
- `Plan settings` > `Advanced` > `usb selective suspend` > disabled
- `Device Manager` > usb > `allow computer to turn off this device to save power` > disabled

Could anybody help to solve this problem